# Javascript Event seen in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

Why is that so if I add an class to the classList of a object, I can see the change via innerHtml of the parent Node e.g class="text", but when I set an event on an object for example onclick = "anyFunc", I cant see it in the innerHtml of the parentNode? And how can I make events show up in innerHtml if added through javascript?

Comment: Your question is worded in an unclear manner. Additionally it may be that you are expecting something that just doesn't happen: Events don't show up in the rendered DOM. Try being clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setAttribute`:

```js
var p=document.getElementById("p");
var s=document.getElementById("s");
console.log("s.parentElement.innerHTML="+s.parentElement.innerHTML);
console.log("p.innerHTML="+p.innerHTML);
function sayHi() { console.log("hi"); }

s.setAttribute("onclick", "sayHi()");
console.log('just did: s.setAttribute("onclick", "sayHi()");');

console.log("s.parentElement.innerHTML="+s.parentElement.innerHTML);
console.log("p.innerHTML="+p.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="p"><span id="s">Hello</span></p>
```